# HTML selection option with javascript doesn't work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, dom

can somebody help me. I try to make some thing happen when i click on anders(value 0), than something need to be vissible. It works in firefox but not in IE

```
<select id="budget" name="budget">
<option value="0" onclick="anders('1')">Anders</option>
<option value="200" onclick="anders('');" selected="selected">&#8364; 200,-</option>
<option value="300" onclick="anders('')">&#8364; 300,-</option>
<option value="400" onclick="anders('')">&#8364; 400,-</option>
<option value="500" onclick="anders('')">&#8364; 500,-</option>
<option value="600" onclick="anders('')">&#8364; 600,-</option>
```

can some body please help me?

Answer (score 2):

You should put an [`onchange` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms536912%28VS.85%29.aspx) handler on the `<select>` instead of many `onclick` event handlers on the `<option>`s.

Comment: +1 - I was just writing up a code sample with this.  IE doesn't support the `onclick` event for `<option>` tags.

Answer (score 1):

Onclick is not a valid handler for option types. you need to use the onchange in the select box:

```
<select id="budget" name="budget" onchange="anders(escape(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value))">
<option value="0">Anders</option>
<option value="200" selected="selected">&#8364; 200,-</option>
<option value="300">&#8364; 300,-</option>
<option value="400">&#8364; 400,-</option>
<option value="500">&#8364; 500,-</option>
<option value="600">&#8364; 600,-</option>
</select>
```

Comment: What's the `escape()` for?  Besides it being an outdated javascript method that doesn't support UTF-8, it seems completely unnecessary here and doesn't look like a true representation of the original code which used `anders('1')` for the first option's onclick.

Comment: @OP; Or you could just use `this.value` instead of going through the whole `this.selectedIndex` bit